# Symfony2 - Twig : HTML <optgroup> Tag

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I need to create a select with  Tag.

this is my code to fill the select

```
        ->add('city', 'entity', array(
            'empty_value' => 'Choisissez une option',
            'class' => 'FrontBundle:City',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                    ->orderBy('c.city', 'ASC');
            },
        ))
```

And this is my code in html.twig

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form_label(form.city, 'Ville') }}
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            {{ form_widget(form.city) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here is the result I want to get:

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Région 1">
     <option value="ville 1">Ville 1</option>
     <option value="ville 2">Ville 2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Région 2">
     <option value="ville 3">Ville 3</option>
     <option value="ville 4">Ville 4</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

Any idea ? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how you want to group the cities but If you already have an entity's parameter to use like a `province` or `region` (or any other related/associated) you can use it in the [group_by option of the entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by), or you can build the optgroup tree using the groupBy clause in your query builder (otherwise you can build the tree manually).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I hope group by region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [gp_sflover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3695819/gp-sflover) said [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781953/symfony2-twig-html-optgroup-tag#comment45841396_28781953), you can use the [`group_by` option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#group-by) of the `entity` field type :

> This is a property path (e.g. `author.name`) used to organize the
>   available choices in groups. It only works when rendered as a select
>   tag and does so by adding `optgroup` elements around options. Choices
>   that do not return a value for this property path are rendered
>   directly under the select tag, without a surrounding optgroup.

So, assuming `region` is a property of `city`, your code should look like this:

```
    ->add('city', 'entity', array(
        'empty_value' => 'Choisissez une option',
        'class' => 'FrontBundle:City',
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                ->orderBy('c.city', 'ASC');
        },
        'group_by' => 'region',
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks @Veve. that's helpful. But how use this in twig.html file.

Comment: That's the beauty of Symfony2 and Twig, you don't have anything more to do, your select will automatically be rendered with optgroups.

Comment: Hi i did this but i get: Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class ....... could not be converted to string. Anyone know what i do wrong ?

Comment: Add `'property' => 'name'` with `name` a string attribute of your entity. You can also add a `__toString()` to your entity instead. @D3F